# Is there a way to make a full backup of my device?

Tags: backup

When I say full, I mean full. Like, everything. Boot partition. System stuff. Every single file and byte. Something I can flash back through odin or otherwise, if I mess up while experimenting with the wrong ROM. Something that can put my mind at ease while experimenting so I don't fear ending up with an expensive paperweight.

I'm basically looking for the android equivalent of what [`dd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning) would do to back up a disk. `dd` creates a full image, including every last byte, that you can write right back. Hell, it even includes the MBR if you point it at a raw device instead of a partition.

Comment: Does a TWRP backup + a full copy of internal storage suffice? That covers at least `/system`, `/data` and `/data/media` (and `/EFS` if you're a Samsung device - do back it up if you can). Everything else should be restorable by Odin when TWRP isn't accessible.

Comment: Good ol' nandroid backups should help. I think TWRP backs the up as .img, which would work with heimdall (ODIN variant)

Comment: @DanBrown TWRP has them in .win format which is just gz'd tar archive (at least from what I remember, for `/system` and `/data` - dunno what's the case for `/boot`).

Comment: @AndyYan The **.win** files don't start with the same bytes. Specifically, I `hexdump`ed **data.f2fs.win**, and the first bytes made up the string **/dontpanic/**. Analyzing **efs.ext4.win** with the same procedure yielded the bytes that made up the string **/wifi/**.